# how to run kubelet as docker container

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

Can I run kubelet as a docker container based on kubernetes v1.6.6? if can do, how to create the image or where to get a image, and also how to run this image?

the following is my ops, but has some problems.

Dockerfile

`FROM i71:5000/ubuntu:14.04
ADD iptables /usr/local/bin/iptables
ADD bin/kubelet /usr/local/bin/kubelet`

docker runing sh

 `#!/bin/bash
    docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq --filter "name=kubelet")
    docker run \
      -d \
      --restart="always" \
      --net="host" \
      -v /data/kubernetes-cluster/ssl:/data/kubernetes-cluster/ssl \
      -v /data/kubernetes-cluster/kube-conf:/data/kubernetes-cluster/kube-conf \
      -v /data/kubernetes-cluster/log:/data/kubernetes-cluster/log \
      -v /data/kubelet:/var/lib/kubelet \
      -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime \
      -v /var/run/:/var/run/ \
      -v /var/log/:/var/log/ \
      --privileged=true \
      --name kubelet \
      i71:5000/kubelet:v1.6.6 \
      /usr/local/bin/kubelet \
      --logtostderr=true \
      --v=0 \
      --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs \
      --api-servers=http://192.168.0.97:8080 \
      --docker-endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:4243 \
      --address=192.168.0.97 \
      --hostname-override=192.168.0.97 \
      --allow-privileged=true \
      --pod-infra-container-image=i71:5000/pod-infrastructure:rhel7 \
      --cluster-dns=10.3.0.2 \
      --experimental-bootstrap-kubeconfig=/data/kubernetes-cluster/kube-conf/bootstrap.kubeconfig \
      --kubeconfig=/data/kubernetes-cluster/kube-conf/kubelet.kubeconfig \
      --require-kubeconfig \
      --cert-dir=/data/kubernetes-cluster/ssl \
      --cluster-domain=cluster.local. \
      --hairpin-mode=promiscuous-bridge \
      --serialize-image-pulls=false`

kubelet prints these errors(my docker damon pid is 5140):

    `E0706 12:11:46.061949       1 container_manager_linux.go:394] open /proc/5140/cgroup: no such file or directory
    E0706 12:11:46.137217       1 container_manager_linux.go:97] Unable to ensure the docker processes run in the desired containers
    E0706 12:16:46.062290       1 container_manager_linux.go:394] open /proc/5140/cgroup: no such file or directory
    E0706 12:16:46.138189       1 container_manager_linux.go:97] Unable to ensure the docker processes run in the desired containers`

if i do volume host dir '/proc', an error occurred by docker damon.

    `docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting\\\"/proc\\\" to rootfs \\\"/data/docker/local-storage/docker/aufs/mnt/6ad53fff3b30e8d709b1be326f5de1314371e174e34806d4d6c6436275b6fbd3\\\" at \\\"/proc\\\" caused \\\"\\\\\\\"/data/docker/local-storage/docker/aufs/mnt/6ad53fff3b30e8d709b1be326f5de1314371e174e34806d4d6c6436275b6fbd3/proc\\\\\\\" cannot be mounted because it is located inside \\\\\\\"/proc\\\\\\\"\\\"\"".`

what should i do, can anyone show me a light?

Comment: It is possible to run kubelet in a container, however it is hard to say where you went off track. What config did you take this from?

Comment: It's all my attempt. most volumes created when I see errors printed by kubelet.but can't volume the /proc dir, something because the container will read/write this dir when the container begin running.

Comment: is there an official document to create kubelet container?

Comment: Perhaps `--privileged` would do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

There is a official docker image called `hyperkube` which contains all Kubernetes binaries, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/#selecting-images

You can find an example systemd service on how to use it for `kubelet` here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes-anywhere/blob/master/phase2/ignition/vanilla/kubelet.service